# Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

¡Hola a Todos! Soy nueva utilizando Spring Boot y me he encontrado con un problema al realizar relaciones uno a muchos. Realicé un ejemplo para poder mostrarles que es lo que está sucediendo.

Tengo dos entidades(persona y mascota). Una Persona puede tener varias mascotas y una Mascota solo puede ser de una Persona.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
public class Persona {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "cedula")
    private Integer cedula;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dueno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Mascota> mascotas = new HashSet<Mascota>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mascota")
public class Mascota {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "serial")
    private Integer serial;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns (foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_persona"), 
    value = { @JoinColumn(name = "dueno", referencedColumnName = "cedula")})
    @JsonBackReference
    private Persona dueno;
}
```

Estoy utilizando FetchType.LAZY. Esto es una estrategia de búsqueda que le indica al proveedor JPA que no busque la asociación relacionada. @OneToMany viene por defecto con esta estrategia de búsqueda mientras que @ManyToOne con FetchType.EAGER. Al correr mi programa de esta manera me lanza el error:

```
Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer
```

Para resolver este problema Intenté utilizar lo siguiente:

```
1- @JsonIdentityInfo
2- @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference
3- @JsonIgnore
```

Siendo el 2 y el 3 los que me funcionaron para poder manejar de una mejor manera la serialización. Aunque luego me dio otro error:

```
JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Busqué hasta el cansancio como resolver este problema y lo único que me funcionó fue crear un Entity Graph pero esto no resolvía el problema de la recursión infinita que se crea. Seguí buscando y al final lo que hice fue utilizar el entity graph junto con un manejador de relaciones bidireccionales. El código quedó de la siguiente manera:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "persona.mascota", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "mascotas")
})
public class Persona {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "cedula")
    private Integer cedula;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dueno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Mascota> mascotas = new HashSet<Mascota>();

/// Getters and Setters
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mascota")
public class Mascota {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "serial")
    private Integer serial;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns (foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_persona"), 
    value = { @JoinColumn(name = "dueno", referencedColumnName = "cedula")})
    @JsonBackReference
    private Persona dueno;

/// Getters and Setters
}
```

Este es el repositorio de Persona

```java
@Transactional
@RepositoryRestResource(path="/personaRepo")
public interface PersonaRepository extends CrudRepository<Persona, Integer>{

    @EntityGraph(value = "persona.mascota", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Optional<Persona> findById(Integer id);

    @EntityGraph(value = "persona.mascota", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    List<Persona> findAll();
}
```

Estos son los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las Personas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien Sabe como resolver esto de una mejor manera, le agradecería mucho que me ayudara.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás usando directamente las entidades de tu modelo de base de datos en la capa de presentación, lo que te va a provocar quebraderos de cabeza:

1. Pides un dato, digamos que una `Persona`
2. Lo obtienes, pero el atributo `mascotas` no se obtiene en ese momento porque tienes definida la carga `LAZY` (es decir, bajo demanda).
3. El objeto llega hasta tu controller, con lo que estás fuera del código que gestiona las sesiones y/o transacciones de la base de datos.
4. Intentas enviar como JSON la instancia de Persona: el serializador intenta convertir, mediante reflexión, el objeto Persona en un documento JSON
5. El objeto Persona realmente no tiene un HashSet, tiene un objeto que cumple la interfaz de Set pero creado por Hibernate para enterarse de cuando estás pidiendo los datos (usando el `getMascotas()`), por lo tanto no tiene los datos que el serializador necesita y no sabe cómo tratar ese objeto

Mi consejo es crear un objeto que rellenes "manualmente" con los datos que necesitas en tu `@Service` y que sea eso lo que llegue a tu controlador. De ese modo puedes controlar exactamente qué mandas y evitar la recursión infinita por un lado y problemas con Hibernate por otro.

Comment: Gracias por responder.. No se si lo que me estas aconsejando es que convierta la entidad a DTO. Si no es así podrías por favor explicarme con el ejemplo y de verdad disculpa.. No me quedó claro.